# OpenVPN server to forward incoming connection to client

Tags: linux, windows, networking, port-forwarding, openvpn

**Scenario**:

- Server on the internet has OpenVPN server running.
- Client-1 at home has app running on port 5000 (UDP and TCP), connecting to Server on it's OpenVPN (app binds to 0.0.0.0).
- Client-2 at work want's to connect to Client-1's app through the internet, without connecting to the same OpenVPN network.
- Both Clients are using Windows and Server uses Linux (Ubuntu).

`Client-1 <===TUN0===> SERVER <===ETH0===> Client-2`

**Question**:

How can I configure OpenVPN to forward incoming connection requests coming to it's eth0 interface's port 5000 to Client-1's tun0 interface's 5000 port, so Client-1's app can serve content back to Client-2 both on UDP and TCP?

Comment: This is the OpenVPN Howto, with the solution of your problem, https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope

Comment: Sorry @MariusMatutiae, that is not about what I have described. Think of the scenario if you would have a dumb router that cannot do port forwarding and you cannot reach inside to Client-1's port from Client'2. Then you would grab a VM out there, set up Openvpn to connect clients and also do the port forwarding for Client-1's specific port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately I have found the answer in this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables).

Some configuration I took from this [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Having port forwarding enabled in `sysctl` I still needed to add some `iptables` rules added to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, it looks something like this:

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#


# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50100 -j DNAT --to-destination [Client-1's vpn address]:50100
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 50100 -j DNAT --to-destination [Client-1's vpn address]:50100

# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES


# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
.
.
.
.
.
# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT


# START OPENVPN RULES
-A FORWARD -d [Client-1's vpn address]/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50100 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d [Client-1's vpn address]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 50100 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# END OPENVPN RULES


# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

With the `sysctl` port forwarding enabled and the ip specific port forwarding `iptables` rules, now the 50100 port is open and forwarded to Client-1's port.

Comment: I have the same setup running OpenVPN on Debian, following DO's tutorial. But I am still not able to forward the port using your method above.

Comment: To extend the accepted answer, you may need to add an enable to your `server.conf` file: push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

Comment: But does this forward through the VPN?

Comment: @Ikon, please tell me what address 10.8.0.0 is there -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov If I remember correctly, that is the address range of the OpenVPN network used. It should match your network in your setup.